# Why is my API throws an error when using authentication mode="Windows"

Tags: c#, restsharp

Somehow when using Windows mode, I get an Exception Error"Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 69, position 41."" weird. Then when I check the result.Content after executing I get like an html page with errors like
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. This is an issue that happens on the IIS Server too.

Below is my RestSharp Code from ActionResult

```cs
var client = new RestClient(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString());
var request = new RestRequest("http://domain.co.za/api/student/getBookedSlotHistory", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddObject(new StudentInput()
{
    StudentNumber = "219193029"//UserIdentity.Username()
});

var result = client.Execute<StudentBookingHistoryOutput>(request);
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentBookingHistoryOutput>(result.Content);
```

Then below is my APIController

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/student/getBookedSlotHistory")]
public async Task<StudentBookingHistoryOutput> GetHistory(StudentInput input)
{
    return await _studentRepository.GetBookingHistoryData(input);
}
```

Comment: You need to authenticate your request.

Comment: I am not familiar with this type of request or your server setup but I do know that when I get errors after switching to windows auth there are 'hopping' issues and the problem is passing the token through multiple hops.  Kerebos was the only solution in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

This actually solved my problem.

```
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```